# How to implement angular $watch function in core javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

As i know that angular watches are evaluated in every digest loop. So, i need such kind of function in core javascript for watch http response json object.

**Somethings like this:-**

```
var oldResponseData='{"name":"Ram","age":"45"}';
function myCustomeWatch(httpResponseData){
  if(httpResponseData===oldResponseData){
     return false;
  }else{
     oldResponseData=httpResponseData;
  }
}
.
.
.
 httpResponseData='{"name":"Ram","age":"46"}';//'{"name":"Ram","age":"45"}' != '{"name":"Ram","age":"46"}'
setInterval(function(){
   myCustomeWatch(httpResponseData);
},3000);
```

Comment: What exactly does a watch function do?

Comment: Use a _setter_ instead of a simple variable for `httpResponseData`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use Object.watch. More info is available [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch)

And here is the [polyfill](https://gist.github.com/eligrey/384583) for ES5 compatible browsers